# Creating a component with data from Redux state that needs to accept a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create snackbar component within my React app that allows me to set alerts from anywhere in the app. I'm using redux-toolkt and so far I have:

- a snackbarSlice with reducers for appendSnackbar (which accepts a text string) and removeSnackbar.
- a Snackbar component that uses the "useSelector" from react-redux to display the first snackbar found in the state then calls removeSnackbar until there are none left.

So far it seems simple enough and works but now I want to include a button in some snackbars that, when clicked, calls a function. The function that needs to be called would be set from the same place I originally dispatched "appendSnackbar." However, setting a function in state breaks Redux principles.

What alternative approaches exist for such a design wherein I maintain a list of snackbars to display along with a function they should call when a button on them is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer with my resolution to this problem.

Step one is to dispatch appendSnackbar from wherever needed. That part has not changed. What has changed is what is stored in the snackbar state. Along with the message, a "methodName" is stored as a string.

Step two, in the snackbar component where the state is read, a switch statement reads "methodName" from the state object and calls which ever method has that name.

Seems far from ideal but given there are only a couple methods that could be needed, it gets the job done.